# How to grant referenced user access to Profile page

Tags: 7, users, entities

I use [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module in many projects. I have a very similar task: Grant access to a profile page for those user who is referenced in that profile. Unfortunately, Node access user reference doesn't work in this case, since it's not a node but a different kind of entity. Is there any solution for this task?

Comment: Should be easy getting this work in a custom module. Just get current user's bid with `global $user`, iterate through referenced users and if current $user->uid matches with any iteration item then just provide access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is ready to use code. For this to work you need to enable the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, add entity reference field on `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` page targeting user entity and setting to unlimited, and finally giving access to `View user profiles` to all `authenticated user` role members.

Create `my_module.info` file and paste:

```
name = My Module
description = Does awesome things. Makes tea. Washes up. Favours of a personal nature.
dependencies[] = entityreference
core = 7.x
```

Create my_module.module file and paste:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_view_alter().
 */
function my_module_user_view_alter(&$build) {
  global $user;
  if ($build['#account']->uid == $user->uid || in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    // Return early if user is administrator or is at their own profile.
    return;
  } elseif (isset($build['field_users'])) {
    foreach ($build['field_users']['#object']->field_users[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $referenced) {
      if ($user->uid == $referenced['target_id']) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  drupal_access_denied();
}
```

Go to a user profile, add some user references and try to view that user's profile as the referenced user to gain access and then as non-referenced user to get denied access.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm working on an other issue, after that I will try this out.

Comment: Any update on this? Takes couple minutes to test the code.

Comment: I'm really grateful your help but this site is a 'side project' besides my other daily tasks. Please, be patient, I hope I can test it soon.

Comment: Finally I have had some time to test your suggestions, thank you for your patience. Basically it seems to be working more or less, but I have still got a few Issues:<br/> 1. *drupal_access_denied()* renders a full page, it duplicates the header 2. This solution works only if all users got *View user profiles* permission.

Comment: After `drupal_access_denied();` an `exit;` command must be placed in order to avoid double page rendering. Apart from this it's a useful sugestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question: This module handles access rights as intended, a profile page is accessible only for referenced users. But in a table generated by Views users can see every profile pages regardless user references. I can bypass it with a filter, but would it be possible to utilize the access right processes of Views?